# Does accepting an answer remove it from the featured page?

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

slm recently kind of out did himself answering one of my bounty questions. Since it had been up for a while, I wanted to leave it on the featured page so that those interested in the question could see that it had been answered. I'm interested in marking his answer as accepted so people know it's confirmed valid but I'm worried that would take it off the page.

So my question is: Before I accept his answer, *will* it take it off the page? Or Does merely withholding the bounty until tomorrow leave it on the list of featured questions?

Answer (score 6):

The active bounty is what keeps the question on the Featured list, regardless of whether there is an accepted answer or not. Accepting an answer won't award the bounty immediately.

If you don't award the bounty manually though, and since you're both the person who asked the question and the one who posted the bounty, it will be automatically awarded to the answer you accepted during the bounty period though.

(See the [bounty help page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for the complete set of rules for automatic bounty awards.)